# trouble with rake db:migrate

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi every one i'm new on ruby on rails so i got this problem with rake db:migrate 
So i use --trace up on it to understand but i didn't get a clue of what to do .
i put my migrate  .rb file below.

```
 $ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
==  AlterUsers: migrating =====================================================
-- rename_table("users", "admin_users")
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'admin_users' already exists: RENAME TABLE `users` TO `admin_users`
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `log'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:211:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:457:in `rename_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/Users/seydoukonate/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20121015072622_alter_users.rb:3:in `up'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `migrate'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:123:in `with_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `__send__'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `ddl_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:153
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:23
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Here is whats inside my _create_user.rb file.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|

      t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
      t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
      t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
      t.string "password", :limit => 40
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

and here is what is inside alter_user.rb file

```
class AlterUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    rename_table("users", "admin_users")
    add_column("admin_users", "username", :string, :limit => 25)
    change_column("admin_users", "email", :string, :limit => 100)
    rename_column("admin_users", "password", "hashed_password")
    add_column("admin_users", "salt", :string, :limit => 40)
    puts "*** About to add and index ***"
    add_index("admin_users", "username")
  end

  def down
    remove_index("admin_users", "username")
    remove_column("admin_users", "salt")
    rename_column("admin_users", "hashed_apssword", "password")
    change_column("admin_users", "email", :string, :default => "", :null => false)
    remove_column("admin_users", "username")
    rename_table("admin_users", "users")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have devise gem installed which already created a table named `admin_users`.

You either need to remove the table `admin_users` (and corresponding migration file) before your run the `alter`; or you can rename `users` to something else than `admin_users`

Comment: so for it to work do i have to do rake db:migrate:down or what'? if i want to remove it

Comment: you can try `rake db:rollback` until it rollbacks `admin_users` table. then delete the migration file and run migration again.

Comment: I've delete the admin_user in the data bases and recreate a new Alter table.rb file but i'm getting a different error. An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled: Mysql2::Error: Can't find file: './simple_cms_development/users.frm' (errno: 2): RENAME TABLE users TO admin_users

Comment: how you've deleted the table? probably you've removed files from filesystem resulting a broken database!

Comment: in the sql program i've executed DROP TABLE admin_user;

Comment: probably it not successful! however, your table name should be `admin_users`. Please Repair all tables and make sure you don't get the said error

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'admin_users' already exists: RENAME TABLE `users` TO `admin_users`
```

It means the table already exists. May be a previous migration already created it.

Comment: so for it to work do i have to do rake db:migrate:down or what'?

Comment: It depends on how you created the table. You should first understand why it's there. Did you already run the migration previously? If so, you should write a different migration that works on the existing database. You can use down as long as the content of down will reset the db to the previous state.

Comment: I've delete the admin_user in the data bases and recreate a new Alter table.rb file but i'm getting a different error.


An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Can't find file: './simple_cms_development/users.frm' (errno: 2): RENAME TABLE `users` TO `admin_users`

Answer (score 0):

For this tutorial i mean (Ruby on Rails 3 Essential Training) if you have issue like described above try to execute

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=0
```

And run

```
rake db:migrate
```